# mfc140ud.dll and vcruntime140d.dll needed for Release compilation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, vcredist

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and this project is from an earlier version of Visual Studio. When I try to open the software compiled in release mode, I receive and error about missing mfc140ud.dll and VCRUNTIME140D.dll.  From what I understand, I should only need these DLLs if I am compiling in Debug mode. What could be causing this?

Comment: Your project settings are probably not correct.  Open your project settings to ensure that the Release build is linking in the non-debug version of the libraries.

Comment: Either your code, or a library you link against has a dependency on the debug version of the language runtime. Make sure that you link against the release version of the language runtime, **and** the release version of any library you use.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, You distributing a DEBUG version of your application.The "d" suffix of "mfc140ud.dll"and"vcruntime140d.dll" indicate it's looking for the DEBUG version of the MFC libraries.

I suggest you should check your project settings.

If you want your application to run not depending on the mfc140u.dll you can simply static link your application with MFC.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't address the core issue, nor is it recommended. Once you statically link against a library, you no longer can exchange CRT objects across DLL boundaries. [Potential Errors Passing CRT Objects Across DLL Boundaries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/potential-errors-passing-crt-objects-across-dll-boundaries) has details. I understand that you're wanting to help. But handing out ill-advised recommendations is bad, no matter how you slice it. Posting this from a user account with *"MSFT"* in its name doubles the odds of this being attributed extra credibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a dependency matter between release and debugging mode.

In my case, I got the same error message with my executable file which is built by 64 bit release.

First, It said that unable to find a vcruntime140d.dll.

[image]

Finally i've got a 0xc000007b error message as follows.

[image]

Finally, i found the point after digging the dependencies of my executable file with libraries which are ocilib,libzip,zlib and iconv.

These libraries are all built with **64-bit debugging mode**.

So, I rebuilt them all to **64-bit release mode**
then the error was gone as you can see the size of files between two pictures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

vc_redist.x64 installing may fix this issue.

Comment: IIRC, the Visual Studio redistributable packages *do not include* the debug versions of DLLs.